# java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.text.DecimalFormat declares multiple JSON fields named maximumIntegerDigits - Android OS 7 and 8

Tags: java, android, gson

**Background :**

This exception rise only on Android 7 and 8, I have checked on Android 6 and it doesn't reproduce.

**Exception :**

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class java.text.DecimalFormat declares multiple JSON fields named maximumIntegerDigits

Any hint about the possible source of this issue ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed just by making the `DecimalFormat` field `static`